# Qt stand-alone app not generating output files

Tags: qt

I have created a standalone Qt application to run on Windows. It is in a form of a questionnaire, where the user answers a few questions, and when it is done, the app should generate a .txt file with the answers in the same folder where the .exe is.

It works fine on my own machine (Win7, 64b). It also runs on other Windows machines that have no Qt installed (tried it on another two Win7 64b and one Win XP).

The problem is, the *first* time the app is run on *some* machines, it does not generate the output text file. It generates it without problems in the subsequent runs of the application. This happened on the XP and one Win7 64b. The other Win7 64b I tested on (other than my own) had no such issues.

I tried to find out what could be causing the problem, but no luck. The application is run from a directory where it is allowed to write, so that would not be the issue.

Comment: it's quite hard to say what's going on with your app without stack trace or\and an error message. Adding (or switching on) logging (http://drdobbs.com/cpp/201804215) for your application should help you to pin point the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to output the complete path to the debug console just before you open the file:

```
qDebug() << "Current Path: " << QDir::currentPath();
```

That might give you some insights on why sometimes it works or not...